# Can I ship a library with Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am re-writing an open source React Native library and I want to use Hooks. Considering Hooks were added in React 16.8, I can assume that there is quite a large chunk of packages installed  in project that do not support 16.8+.

Is there a way for me to write the source code with Hooks and  transpile it  so it can be used with any version of React?

Comment: why don't you increment the major version number and simply state in your upgrade docs that in order to use the new version, you need React 16.8?

Comment: I mean this is certainly logical, I don't really want to prevent Users from getting new features because they're not on 16.8. I could always not use hooks and it'd solve my dilemma. I just wondered if there was a way.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to transpile hooks into class component lifecycle methods.

Comment: You could have a dependency of React 16.8+. Which in theory would force people to use version 16.8 or higher. Also, I could be wrong but I thought there was a way to use Webpack and Babel to transpile supported features (I think they lag behind on new features -- so I'm not positive if Hooks are supported yet) to "vanilla" JavaScript. I'd suggest looking into how to create a "React component library" and how they set up their packaging/bundling.